# Using a variable within the .items() method within a function - AttributeError: module 'G' has no attribute 'args'

Tags: python, dictionary, attributes, attributeerror

What is the best way to do what I am trying to do here, which is to define a variable within a function that is then used in a method, but I obtain the error:
`AttributeError: module 'reference_A_Z' has no attribute 'args'`

Is there a better way to do this?

```
# Import .py
import reference_A_Z as ref

# Define function to obtain the key:value 
def function(VAR1):
    for key, value in ref.VAR1.items():
        try:
            foo = foo1
        except KeyError:
            print("KeyError")

# Define args.input
args = parser.parse_args('-i RefA'.split())

# Run the function
function(args.input)
```

I have made sure that `reference_A_Z` contains a dictionary called `RefA`. If I substitute with the string `RefA` the function works and there are no errors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to dynamically reference objects within a module.  The dot-notation won't work because the attribute will not get substituted as a variable.  Instead, you can use `getattr`.

```
def function(VAR1):
    try:
        obj = getattr(ref, VAR1)
    except AttributeError:
        print(f'No object named {VAR1} in ref.')

    for key, value in obc.items():
        try:
            foo = foo1
        except KeyError:
            print("KeyError")
```

Comment: Fantastic. Works perfectly. I should also mention another workaround a colleague showed me was to make `reference_A_Z` a nested dict in of itself, then use notation via: ```def function(VAR1):
    for key, value in ref[VAR1].items():
```
but your way is much more elegant